# SQL Server Always Encrypted with Access

Tags: sql-server, encryption, always-encrypted

I see SQL Server 2016 SP1 All Editions now have "Always Encrypted" available. From looking around, it appears there's a new ODBC driver that will work with the "Always Encrypted" data.

With the caveats in the SQL Server documentation about working with encrypted columns, does anyone have experience using this encryption with Microsoft Access? Will it work with Access 2010, or does it require newer versions?

Is there a noticeable performance hit from the encrypting/decrypting? Am I reading it right that since joins and where clauses require additional handling for encrypted columns, best practice would be to not use sensitive columns as keys.

Also, I have an Access Project -- can this work with Access 2010 in a Project (adp), or will I have to update to an .accdb version of the application?

Comment: Doesn't Access use DSNs defined in ODBC administrator? If so, then as long you use the newer driver that supports "Always Encrypted", the encryption would behave like Oracle TDE ("Transparent Database Encryption"), i.e. completely transparent to the application (or Access, in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post with a solution on how to configure Access with Always Encrypted: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b9eea19c-1943-4b25-b07d-9193f7b7dab0/odbc-always-encrypted-problems?forum=sqldataaccess.